# Generation pdf truncated

Tags: pdf, itext

I have to transform a HTML badly built in PDF. 
I transformed the HTML file into XTML with the class Tidy.
Then, generated my PDF with XMLWorkerHelper.

It's work but the generated PDF is not correct.
The images are missing and the text is truncated on certain files.
What specific configuration may I use to solve this problem?
It is the first time when I use these class and it's not easy.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your use of the word `class` suggests you wrote some code. Please [edit] your question and at the very least add the language you used. If you think the problem is in your actual code, add a [mcve] as well.

Comment: `XMLWorkerHelper` seems to indicate that you are using [tag:itext] or [tag:itextsharp]. Please tag your question accordingly. Furthermore provide code (as @RadLexus suggested) and also the tidied-up HTML (or at least some of it showing how the images and the truncated text are created).

Answer (score 0):

I have files html badly constituted to transform into PDF. 
I thus used at first Tidy to format them in XHTML and then XMLWorkerHelper to generate the pdf.
I've used itextpdf-5.4.2 xmlworker-5.4.2 .

```
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documentPDF, new FileOutputStream(pdfFilename));   
 documentPDF.open();
  XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, documentPDF,                new FileInputStream(HTMLFileName));
```

I can't post my file, it's too big.